# SQL ERROR : Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below with a default value column as [IsProcessed]

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Kovair_JileEventHistory]') 
                 AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kovair_JileEventHistory]
    (
        [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [GeneratedActionId] [char](36) NOT NULL,
        [BaseUrl] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [ProjectName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [EntityName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [EntityId] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [RelatedEntityName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [RelatedEntityId] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [ActionName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [LoopbackEventName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [LastUpdatedOnGMT] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LastUpdatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [IsProcessed] [char](1) NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF__Kovair_Ji__IsPro__5224328E]') 
                 AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Kovair_JileEventHistory] 
        ADD DEFAULT ('N') FOR [IsProcessed]
END
```

When I am executing this lines in a different system if I execute it once its working fine but on the second time when I am executing it its giving me an error as below.

> Msg 1781, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
> Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 26
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

But when ever I am doing the same in my system from where I have generated this script I am able to execute it multiple time without any error.

I think

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF__Kovair_Ji__IsPro__5224328E]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Kovair_JileEventHistory] ADD  DEFAULT ('N') FOR [IsProcessed]
END
```

in this lines the part where OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF__Kovair_Ji__IsPro__5224328E]') is system specific.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is flawed:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DF__Kovair_Ji__IsPro__5224328E]') 
  AND type = 'D'
)
```

For a few reasons:

1. You let the system name the constraint, which means every time you create the table, that system will come up with a new name. You should always explicitly name your constraints so that scripts like this can be made more predictable and so that you can have a sane naming convention.

   ```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename 
      ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomethingSmarter
      DEFAULT('N') FOR IsProcessed;
   ```
2. You're basically just saying "is there a default constraint on this table with this name" but you've hard-coded the constraint name. It's possible this could behave differently on a *different* system for a different reason - say there is another column that starts with `IsPro...` and it *happens* to get the *same* quasi-random system-generated constraint name.
3. If you know what column and what type of constraint, a much safer (and admittedly more verbose) check is to ignore the constraint name and go after the table + column name:

   ```
    IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
       WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Kovair_JileEventHistory')
       AND EXISTS
       (
          SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns AS c 
           WHERE c.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
             AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
             AND c.name = N'IsProcessed')
       )
    )
    BEGIN
      -- now I know there is no default constraint
      -- on this column, no matter what it's named
    END
   ```

   I would even argue for something more verbose, since at scale [some of the metadata functions do not obey isolation semantics](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions), which might be problematic depending on the scope of the change and the recoverability of the entire script:

   ```
    IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
       INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
         ON t.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id
         AND t.name = N'Kovair_JileEventHistory'
         AND t.[schema_id] = 1
       WHERE EXISTS
       ...
   ```